Dev build error compiling JS failed import declaration must be at top level of module
I have finished my app using expo SDK 52 and made a local and EAS development build of it which is both succesful at building the artifact, and i can install it on my emulator using Android studio.
When launching the app however i am greeted with the following error and no further stacktrace or logs. I do not have any non top level import statements in my code and my app also runs fine in Expo Go. I havent changed the metro or babel configs either. What could be causing this problem to occur only with dev builds?
Sorry for the limited information but i dont have more either and dont know where the problem can be. Happy to provide more info/code if requested.
There was a problem loading the project
The development build encountered the following error
Compiling JS failed: 1208:3 import declaration must be at top level of module
run
NativeRunnable.Java
handleCallback
Handler.Java
dispatchMessage
Handler.Java
dispatchMessage
MessageQueueThreadHandler.Java
loopOnce
Looper.java
loop
Looper.java
lambda$startNewBackgroundThread$2
MessageQueueThreadImpl.java
run
DB$$SyntheticClass
run
Thread.java

